# What does the JSHint option "undef" do?

Tags: javascript, jshint

From reading the [documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#undef) the setting `undef` seems to be what controls the "x is not defined" warnings. But setting it to false does not stop those warnings. So this leaves me wondering what `undef` actually does.

Could someone please explain this better than the documentation does?

*Note: To ignore these warnings I had to use `/*jshint -W117 */`*

Comment: In the JSHint Gutter Sublime Text 3 plugin, which runs off of the global node install of JSHint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `undef` option, when enabled, warns whenever *non-local* (neither a parameter nor "var" variable in scope) variable usage is found.

Taking the code in [the example](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#undef), the following results in `'myvar' is not defined.` (This warning indicates that the code may result in a ReferenceError when the code is run; not that the value is "undefined".)

```
/*jshint undef:true */
function test() {
  var myVar = 'Hello, World';
  console.log(myvar); // Oops, typoed here. JSHint with undef will complain
}
```

When disabling the option there is no warning as it's assumed that the intent was to access the `myvar` *gobal* variable; this can in turn be accepted/validated with the [global directive](http://www.jshint.com/docs/), and the following is once again warning-free.

```
/*jshint undef:true */
/*global myvar*/
function test() {
  var myVar = 'Hello, World';
  console.log(myvar); // Yup, we wanted the global anyway!
}
```